# How to update parsed JSON data using delegates (no table)

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a file which is parsing the JSON data and another file which calls the function and tries to retrieve the data. However, it seems that it can't update into the variable I want it too. I used this format (using tables) in another project when parsing data and it used `tableView.reloadData()`. Is there something like this but not for tables?

Here is the code for the file that calls the function to parse the JSON and tries to set it as `member`. However when I `print(member.first_name)`, it just appears as `hi`

```
class ProfileVC: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var NameText: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var IDText: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var GenderText: UILabel!
    
    var MemberManager = GetMember()
    var member: MemberModel = MemberModel(id: " ", first_name: "hi ", last_name: " ", gender: " ")
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        MemberManager.delegate = self
        MemberManager.fetchMember()
        
        print(member.first_name)
        NameText.text = "member?.first_name"

    }
    
    
}

//MARK: - GetMemberDelegate
extension ProfileVC: GetMemberDelegate {
    func didUpdateStatus(_ getMember: GetMember, member: MemberModel) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.member = member
        }

    }
    
    
    func didFailWithError(_ error: Error) {
        print("ei")
        print(error)
    }
    
    
}
```

Here is the code I used to parse the JSON.

```
import Foundation

protocol GetMemberDelegate {
    func didUpdateStatus(_ getMember: GetMember, member: MemberModel)
    func didFailWithError(_ error: Error)
}

struct GetMember {
    // GET https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/members/{member-id}.json
    let getMemberString = "https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/members/M001157.json"
    
    var delegate: GetMemberDelegate?
    
    var urlUpcomingFinalString: String?

    // Forms URL
    func fetchMember() {
        let urlMember = NSURL(string: getMemberString)!
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: urlMember as URL)
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue(Constant.APIKEY, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-API-Key")
        
        performRequest(request)
    }
    
    // Performs request
    func performRequest (_ urlRequest: NSURLRequest) {
        let session = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest as URLRequest) {data, response, error in
            if error != nil {
                self.delegate?.didFailWithError(error!)
                print("No")
                return
            }
            if let safeData = data {
                if let mem = self.parseJSONMember(safeData) {
                    self.delegate?.didUpdateStatus(self, member: mem)
                    
                }
            }
        }
        session.resume()
    }
    
    // Parsing JSON
    func parseJSONMember(_ memberData: Data) -> MemberModel?{
        // var member: [MemberModel] = []
        
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                
        do {
            let decodedDataGetMember = try decoder.decode(MemberJSONFormat.self, from: memberData)
            let id = decodedDataGetMember.results[0].id
            let first_name = decodedDataGetMember.results[0].first_name
            // let middle_name = decodedDataGetMember.results[0].middle_name
            let last_name = decodedDataGetMember.results[0].last_name
            let gender = decodedDataGetMember.results[0].gender
            print(first_name)
            
            let memberItem = MemberModel(id: id, first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name, gender: gender)

            return memberItem
            
        } catch {
            self.delegate?.didFailWithError(error)
            print("error")
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: `fetchMember()` is going to be *asynchronous*. Search for "Swift callback functions" or "Swift completion handlers" to learn how to deal with this situation. You can also use the new "async/await" introduced in Swift 5.5 if you want. Unrelated, but if you conform to the Swift standards of variable names starting with lowercase letters and types starting with uppercase, it'll make it easier for others to read your code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your tips! I believe I was already using a completion handler. When I write `DispatchQueue.main.async { NameText.text = member.first_name}` it updates fine. Is there a way to update the variable `member` then use its values or does it always need to be inside the dispatch clause?

Comment: I don’t see any completion handlers in your code. Yes, it’s possible to update member.